# Self Closing vs Non Self Closing

Tags: html, tags, element

Can someone explain what makes an ELEMENT self-closing or non-self closing? It might be a silly question by a rookie, but I would really want to know if there is some sort of rule to implement to know the difference between the two. Thank you in advance for any guidance you can provide!

Comment: A self closing tag is also known as a void element. As such, a void element is an element whose content model never allows it to have contents under any circumstances. Input tags, br, hr, img, etc - all of this tags cannot contain content inside the tag. All of the “content” exists as an attribute.

Comment: Makes sense now, thank you so much

Answer (score 2):

[Self closing tags (`<tag />`) don't exist in HTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Void_element#self-closing_tags). The slash is just ignored by the parser.

This means that those tags simply don't require closing. In fact, closing them with something like (`<tag></tag>`) is invalid HTML, and that is for a good reason: [they don't have an end tag](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/syntax.html#elements-2:void-elements-2).

They are called **void elements** because, as there is no end tag, no content can be put between the start and the end tag. If you are curious, there's a [list with all void elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Void_element). There aren't that many.

That being said, there is no harm in adding the trailing slash on a void element's tag. It is ignored in HTML, but it is required in XML. So if you want your HTML to be valid XML, you may use the "self closing syntax".

Answer (score 0):

Self-closing tags like link, br, img.. can't contain any other elements just attributes so there is no need to make them something else, but non-self closing like div, span, h1, a .. can contain other elements and of course take attributes because that they're non-slf closing

Answer (score 0):

For some elements a self-closing tag is a shorthand notation for an opening and closing tag in one its used to communicate lack of content in between the opening and closing tags so rather than typing  for example (with no space at all in between) it would be written in one single tag .
Modern html does not allow the usage of self-closing tags because there is a difference between an inherently empty element and an element that is permitted to have content but doesn’t have any at the moment hence the self-closing  tag doesn’t communicate as much as  the browser will ignore the / and interpret it as a starting tag .

Comment: Your answer *really* needs some punctuation and a bit of clarity.

Answer (score 0):

Simply,

Self-closing/ Single/ Unpaired tag is a tag that doesn't need a closing tag separately and cannot have other elements/tags in it. `(<tag>)`

```
example: <img>, <br>, <hr>, <link>, ...
```

on the other hand,
Non-self-closing/ Basic/ Paired tag want to have separate closing tag and can have other elements/tags in it. `(<tag>...</tag>)`

```
example: <h1>...</h1>, <p>...</p>, <div>...</div>, ...
example for tag within a tag (nested): <h1>...<p>...</p>...</h1>
```